# If statement not returning correct value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am doing a date compare with ticket items, and if the ticket is closed it compares it to the close date.  If ticket is still active it does the age to our current day.  The code is skipping the if statement even if it is true.  I made sure they are both strings while doing the compare.  I have tried many things and can't seem to find out why.  Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

```
Dim BlankRow As Integer
Dim Created As Integer
Dim DDiff As Date
Dim Test As String
Dim Test2 As String
Dim Test3 As String
Dim TestDate2 As Date
Dim TestDate3 As Date
Dim ValHold As Integer
Dim original As String
Dim original2 As String
Dim Compare As Integer
Dim Status As Integer
Dim CellStat As String
Dim Stuff As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range

 i = 2
Do While i < BlankRow

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Created", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set Rng2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Updated", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set Rng3 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("Status")
Created = Rng.Column
Compare = Rng2.Column
Status = Rng3.Column
original = cells(i, Created)
Test = cells(i, Created)
Test2 = cells(i, Compare)

TestDate = CDate(Test)
TestDate2 = CDate(Test2)
cells(i, Created) = TestDate
cells(i, Compare) = TestDate2
CellStat = cells(i, Status)
Stuff = "Closed "

If Len(CellStat) = Len(Stuff) Then
    DDiff = cells(i, Compare) - cells(i, Created)
    Days = (Int(DDiff))
    ValHold = Days
    cells(i, Created) = ValHold
    cells(i, Created).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

Else
    DDiff = Now - cells(i, Created)

    Days = (Int(DDiff))
    ValHold = Days
    cells(i, Created) = ValHold

End If
i = i + 1

Loop

    Function fFirstBlankRow() As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim BlankRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
i = 1
Do While BlankRow < 1
    If cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
        BlankRow = i
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
fFirstBlankRow = BlankRow

End Function
```

Comment: Could you please post a little more code? We have no idea how your variables are defined, nor what that `Loop` is. see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is the case always the same, have you tried using `UCASE(CellStat)=Ucase(Stuff)` or `Option Compare Text` at the top of the module?

Comment: @VincentG I added the rest of the variable and ranges for the code.  thanks!

Comment: @Nathan_Sav The case will either be "In Progress" or "Closed" , but both skip to else even though closed should go through the if

Comment: You didn't declare `i`, `Rng`, `Rng2`, or `Rng3`. If this is in fact your complete code then you are not using `Option Explicit` (which whould be used for robust VBA). You never initialized `BlankRow` so it has the default value of `0`. You give the undeclared `i` an initial value of `2`. Thus the loop `Do While i < BlankRow` never executes.

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry, I forgot to include that function, I added the rest of the items, I mistakenly didn't copy it all.  This should be all of the code for this

Comment: Why don't you just set a breakpoint, step through the code and look at the value ?

Comment: Even with your modified code, `i` is still undeclared. A small thing in some ways, but it indicates a failure to use `Option Explicit`. Since `i < BlankRow` can never be true -- none of the code in the `Do While` loop ever executes.

Comment: I have, and when you highlight over them, they both have the value "Closed" but it still passes.  I tried declaring both of the variables as strings as well but still does not pass. @PatrickHonorez

Comment: @JohnColeman so add option explicit to the module as well as declare I as a variable?

Comment: You have lots of code outside any function... It shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `Option Explicit` should be added to the top of all modules (do it once and for all: in the VBA editor options enable "Require Variable Declaration"). Your code is still an unexecutable fragment which doesn't seem to give any nonzero value to `BlankRow` hence contains a loop which should never execute. Why not give a [mcve]?

Comment: Figured it out, The length of the CelllStat was returning and extra space compared to Closed, so I added an extra space and it worked correctly. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Scouter I meant case as in a <> A not a=A, if it is free text, then you could be entering "Closed" "closed" "closeD" etc.